# How to define the types of parameters in a Haskell type constructor?

Tags: function, haskell, types

Imagine a standard construction of a Tree first:

```
data Tree k = Leaf | Node k (Tree k) (Tree k)
```

I want to implement a version of this where I deal with duplicate entries by counting them, so I have type like this:

```
data Tree k count = Leaf | Node k count (Tree k count) (Tree k count)
```

Accordingly my code is:

```
tree_insert :: Ord k => k -> Tree k count -> Tree k count
tree_insert k Leaf = Node k 1 Leaf Leaf
tree_insert k (Node n count l r)
    | k == n = Node n (count+1) l r
    | k < n  = Node n count (tree_insert k l) r
    | k > n  = Node n count l (tree_insert k r)
```

If you try to use this code however, you will get the following error:

> Could not deduce (Num count) arising from the literal ‘1’

To fix it I changed the type declaration for the function to this:

```
tree_insert :: (Ord k, Num count) => k -> Tree k count -> Tree k count
```

However down the line I ran into further problems. To me it seems like Haskell is telling me that, without the `Num count`, it doesn't know what type it is meant to be and therefore when I assign it as 1 in the first pattern, it produces the error. The `Num count` really doesn't seem like a good way to solve the problem. Ideally, I should be able to define what type count is when I make the initial type declaration, something like:

```
data Tree k count = Leaf | Node k count (Tree k count) (Tree k count)
where count is Int
```

Obviously the above code is no good, but an example of the kind of thing I'm thinking of.

If what I want is possible, or less ideally if there is another way to approach this issue, I'd love to hear it. The emphasis is on definition of data types and functions and all, not just this specific problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If you always want `count` to be `Int`, you could define it so in `Tree`: `data Tree k = Leaf | Node k Int (Tree k Int) (Tree k Int)`. No change required to your function, just the signature.

Comment: Awesome amigo, that completely did the trick. I had to go and get rid of the `count` part from the `Tree k count` in my function signatures as well as in the initial declaration of the type, exactly like you said! Put that in an answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: "The Num count really doesn't seem like a good way to solve the problem" - this *is* the Haskell way of solving the problem.

Comment: @user2407038 Num count isn't specific enough. As far as I'm concerned, Haskell is about strict typing, so if I know it'll always be Int then I would like to define it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two alternatives here. The more straightforward one is to just not parametrize `count` over the `Tree` type.

```
data Tree k = Leaf | Node k Int (Tree k) (Tree k)

tree_insert :: Ord k => k -> Tree k -> Tree k
tree_insert ...
```

Alternately, if you envision yourself needing the more general tree type sometimes, you could stick with a type synonyn.

```
data Tree k count = Leaf | Node k count (Tree k count) (Tree k count)
type TreeInt k = Tree k Int

tree_insert :: Ord k => k -> TreeInt k -> TreeInt k
tree_insert ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original tree type is already fully parametric in the type of data stored at each node; you can work with a tree that stores `(k, Int)` values instead of just `k` values.

```
data Tree k = Leaf | Node k (Tree k) (Tree k)

tree_insert :: a -> Tree (a, Int) -> Tree (a, Int)
tree_insert k Leaf = Node (k, 1) Leaf Leaf
tree_insert k (Node (n, count) l r)
  | k == n = Node (n, count+1) l r
  | k < n  = Node (n, count) (tree_insert k l) r
  | k > n  = Node (n, count) l (tree_insert k r)
```

Comment: This is great too, another awesome way to do it. Thanks!